# Images are Getting cached in UWP application

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-store-apps

In my UWP application I am binding the images from azure. It is getting cached when it get the response. When I change the image in the azure it's not reflecting in my UI, Instead it display the image from cache.
Is there any way to clear the cache of my UWP application or to restrict the application to cache images?.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried `CreateOptions="IgnoreImageCache"`?

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Url}" 
                     CreateOptions="IgnoreImageCache" 
                     DecodePixelWidth="120" 
                     DecodePixelHeight="120" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

But make sure you set the proper decode pixel width/height to avoid using unnecessary memory.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage#Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_Imaging_BitmapImage_CreateOptions) -

> You should only use BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache in cases
>   where you know that the source image file as retrieved by Uniform
>   Resource Identifier (URI) has the potential to change over time.
>   Otherwise, setting CreateOptions to use
>   BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache causes all newly retrieved image
>   sources to be decoded again, which can negatively impact performance.

So maybe try setting `None` as the default value for `CreateOptions`, and only update it to `IgnoreImageCache` once you are absolutely sure that the image has been updated by the cloud. Note `CreateOptions` is also a `dependency property`, so you should be able to use data binding too.

Comment: I was initially setting the source property directly on the `Image` element (not on `BitmapImage`) and I was using x:Bind which worked fine. But when using this solution, x:Bind does not work. Is there any way to use x:Bind with this?

Comment: is there any way, to disable the cache in the whole app?