# How to reload an image in XAML?

Tags: c#, image, xaml, uwp

I am coding a UWP. In the interface of this app there is an Image under a button and an ObservableCollection binded to a collection of images.

```
<Image VerticalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Fill"
    x:Name="FlatWallpaperUI"/>
```

Those images, however, get processed and colors change when selecting a certain accent color.
For example, when the app is launched the image is loaded with the correct colors:

[image: The Image with the colors applied to it at the launce of the app]

I am trying to reload those images by resetting the ObservableCollection or reassigning a Bitmapimage to the Image in XAML.
for example I reassign the bitmapimage to the image under button:

```
ButtonImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/wallpaper2.png"));
```

and for the ObservableCollection I try to empty it and then I read the items:

```
Items.Clear();
Items.Add(new ItemClass
  {
    Name = "First item",
    Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/wallpaper1.png"))
  });
Items.Add(new ItemClass
  {
    Name = "Second item",
    Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/wallpaper2.png"))
  });
```

I know this might be the wrong approach but I have been researching for a while with no clear solution so far.

on this image you see that the colors has changed but the image itself did not!

[image: This is the Image after I change the color]

Even though the Image itself that is supposed to be processed has changed successfully !

[image: Even though the Image itself has been changed!]

How can I get around this and Update the Image when its supposed to?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: "I am trying to reload those images by resetting the ObservableCollection or reassigning a Bitmapimage to the Image in XAML. " - to make the answer complete, please include the code where you perform these actions.

Comment: I am sorry for the unclarity in the question... what I mean by reassigning a bitmapimags is that I set the Image source to the same image again hoping it would reload it into the interface. I have added this to the question.

Comment: You just have an image control why do you use `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: I could not figure out your requirement from the above description, could share more code such as you xaml binding design or give a simple sample.

Comment: Because I could not get the complete code, so I suppose bitmapimage cache cause this issue. please refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45143530/images-are-getting-cached-in-uwp-application) first and let me know your test result.

Comment: The thing is I don't know where to start describing the needed code. Al I need is a way to refresh a collection elements (images) and re-fetch them from source after modification

Comment: @AsemKhen, Does the below answer work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: I agree that you could have shared more code. The pictures are nice but are not helping a lot to solve your issue.

Second: My guess here is you are assuming changing a property of an element of your ObservableCollection will trig the update, which is not the case. In case I'm right here is a possible solution, if my guess is bad edit your question and clarify:

You can create your own ObservableCollection like this and listen to the modifications of some of the elements:

```
public class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(String PropName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropName));
        }
    }

    protected void SetAndRaisePropertyChanged<T>(ref T Prop, T value, [CallerMemberName] String PropName = "")
    {
        Prop = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(PropName);
    }
}

public class CustomCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : ModelBase
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler ChildrenPropertyChanged;
    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        base.ClearItems();

        foreach (var item in this)
        {
            DisposeItem(item);
        }
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
        item.PropertyChanged += Model_PropertyChanged;
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        base.RemoveItem(index);
        DisposeItem(this[index]);
    }

    private void DisposeItem(ModelBase model)
    {
        model.PropertyChanged -= Model_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChildrenPropertyChanged.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Then in your code you can listen like this:

```
private CustomCollection<ItemClass> m_Items = new CustomCollection<ItemClass>();
public CustomCollection<ItemClass> Items
{
    get { return m_Items; }
    set => SetAndRaisePropertyChanged(ref m_Items, value);
}
```

[...]

```
Items.ChildrenPropertyChanged += Items_ChildrenPropertyChanged;
```

[...]

```
private void Items_ChildrenPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    [...] // here you force the refresh by raising the property changed for example
}
```

Comment: This is a good start. I am sorry I am unclear with the question and the lack of code in it. the thing is I don't know how to start with the code. the idea is that the observable collection (A collection of BitmabImage) binded to the UI. Those Images are in a folder. The app changes the colors on those Images. But those changes don't appear in the UI unless I restart the app - reload the images from sources. (The observableCollection Items are the same, it is just the Images that get color changes) In this case, using `PropertyChangedEventArgs` might work.

Comment: Ok, just to be sure, (since it may depend on the number of images) do you really need to put them in an observableCollection? They could be single properties which may avoid all the mechanic I posted. If for whatever reason you think it easier to handle them this way, I think my code may help. In any case you may manually call the RaisePropertyChanged method on the images you know have been modified if you still have an update issue, at least to try.